# vmbuilder throws a lot of warnings and errors but complete process. But guest OS not booting

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, kvm

**I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.**

I did `apt install qemu-kvm vmbuilder` and configured bridged networking with the networking manager in Gnome.

```
virsh
list --all
```

Shows me the Guest

```
start testguest
```

succeed with no errors.

I executed following command to create the guest:

```
vmbuilder kvm ubuntu --suite xenial --flavour virtual --arch amd64 --libvirt qemu:///system --hostname testguest --domain my.local --bridge br0 --mem 8000 -cpus 4 -v --rootsize=8800 --swapsize=500 --user=rex --name=administrator --pass=blabla -o -d /var/local/machines/ --addpkg openssh-server --addpkg avahi-daemon --addpkg acpid > /home/rex/vmbuilder.log 2>&1
```

This is the generated Log:

```
2018-01-31 14:22:55,643 INFO    : logging to file: /tmp/tmp5gzDxH
2018-01-31 14:22:55,783 INFO    : Calling hook: preflight_check
2018-01-31 14:22:55,786 INFO    : Calling hook: set_defaults
2018-01-31 14:22:55,787 INFO    : Calling hook: bootstrap
2018-01-31 14:24:19,868 INFO    : Calling hook: configure_os
2018-01-31 14:24:25,646 INFO    : 
Extracting templates from packages: 56%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
2018-01-31 14:24:50,617 INFO    : W: --force-yes is deprecated, use one of the options starting with --allow instead.
2018-01-31 14:24:51,974 INFO    : 
2018-01-31 14:24:51,974 INFO    : Current default time zone: 'Etc/UTC'
2018-01-31 14:24:51,977 INFO    : Local time is now:      Wed Jan 31 13:24:51 UTC 2018.
2018-01-31 14:24:51,977 INFO    : Universal Time is now:  Wed Jan 31 13:24:51 UTC 2018.
2018-01-31 14:24:51,977 INFO    : 
2018-01-31 14:24:53,933 INFO    : Generating locales (this might take a while)...
2018-01-31 14:24:54,802 INFO    :   en_US.UTF-8... done
2018-01-31 14:24:54,802 INFO    : Generation complete.
2018-01-31 14:24:56,663 INFO    : 
Extracting templates from packages: 34%
Extracting templates from packages: 68%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
2018-01-31 14:25:30,462 INFO    : W: --force-yes is deprecated, use one of the options starting with --allow instead.
2018-01-31 14:25:33,186 INFO    : Cleaning up
2018-01-31 14:25:33,187 INFO    : Calling hook: preflight_check
2018-01-31 14:25:33,224 INFO    : Calling hook: configure_networking
2018-01-31 14:25:33,234 INFO    : Calling hook: create_partitions
2018-01-31 14:25:33,235 INFO    : Creating disk image: "/tmp/tmpJlEQzc" of size: 9300MB
2018-01-31 14:25:33,254 INFO    : Adding partition table to disk image: /tmp/tmpJlEQzc
2018-01-31 14:25:33,296 INFO    : Adding type 4 partition to disk image: /tmp/tmpJlEQzc
2018-01-31 14:25:33,296 INFO    : Partition at beginning of disk - reserving first cylinder
2018-01-31 14:25:33,303 INFO    : Warning: The resulting partition is not properly aligned for best performance.
2018-01-31 14:25:33,336 INFO    : Adding type 3 partition to disk image: /tmp/tmpJlEQzc
2018-01-31 14:25:33,343 INFO    : [0] ../../libparted/filesys.c:148 (ped_file_system_type_get): File system alias linux-swap(new) is deprecated
2018-01-31 14:25:33,372 INFO    : Creating loop devices corresponding to the created partitions
2018-01-31 14:25:33,530 INFO    : Creating file systems
2018-01-31 14:25:33,534 INFO    : mke2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
2018-01-31 14:25:34,654 INFO    : Calling hook: configure_mounting
2018-01-31 14:25:34,662 INFO    : Calling hook: mount_partitions
2018-01-31 14:25:34,663 INFO    : Mounting target filesystems
2018-01-31 14:25:36,922 INFO    : Calling hook: install_bootloader
2018-01-31 14:25:39,192 INFO    : E: Can not write log (Is /dev/pts mounted?) - posix_openpt (2: No such file or directory)
2018-01-31 14:25:44,520 INFO    : update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
2018-01-31 14:25:44,545 INFO    : invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
2018-01-31 14:25:44,678 INFO    : Removing update-grub hooks from /etc/kernel-img.conf in favour of
2018-01-31 14:25:44,678 INFO    : /etc/kernel/ hooks.
2018-01-31 14:25:44,798 INFO    : Searching for GRUB installation directory ... 
2018-01-31 14:25:44,798 INFO    : No GRUB directory found.
2018-01-31 14:25:44,799 INFO    :  To create a template run 'mkdir /boot/grub' first.
2018-01-31 14:25:44,799 INFO    :  To install grub, install it manually or try the 'grub-install' command.
2018-01-31 14:25:44,799 INFO    :  ### Warning, grub-install is used to change your MBR. ###
2018-01-31 14:25:44,799 INFO    : 
2018-01-31 14:25:45,346 INFO    : W: --force-yes is deprecated, use one of the options starting with --allow instead.
2018-01-31 14:25:46,423 INFO    : Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
2018-01-31 14:25:46,428 INFO    : findfs: unable to resolve 'UUID=abbb9598-7d03-46a8-8a3c-24c9960ef757'
2018-01-31 14:25:46,430 INFO    : Cannot determine root device.  Assuming /dev/hda1
2018-01-31 14:25:46,431 INFO    : This error is probably caused by an invalid /etc/fstab
2018-01-31 14:25:46,501 INFO    : Searching for default file ... Generating /boot/grub/default file and setting the default boot entry to 0
2018-01-31 14:25:46,503 INFO    : Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
2018-01-31 14:25:46,506 INFO    : Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... 
2018-01-31 14:25:46,507 INFO    : 
2018-01-31 14:25:46,507 INFO    : Could not find /boot/grub/menu.lst file. 
2018-01-31 14:25:46,507 INFO    : Generating /boot/grub/menu.lst
2018-01-31 14:25:46,570 INFO    : Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
2018-01-31 14:25:46,732 INFO    : grep: /boot/config*: No such file or directory
2018-01-31 14:25:46,807 INFO    : Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done
2018-01-31 14:25:46,807 INFO    : 
2018-01-31 14:25:47,009 INFO    : Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
2018-01-31 14:25:47,015 INFO    : findfs: unable to resolve 'UUID=abbb9598-7d03-46a8-8a3c-24c9960ef757'
2018-01-31 14:25:47,017 INFO    : Cannot determine root device.  Assuming /dev/hda1
2018-01-31 14:25:47,017 INFO    : This error is probably caused by an invalid /etc/fstab
2018-01-31 14:25:47,082 INFO    : Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
2018-01-31 14:25:47,086 INFO    : Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
2018-01-31 14:25:47,193 INFO    : Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
2018-01-31 14:25:47,327 INFO    : grep: /boot/config*: No such file or directory
2018-01-31 14:25:47,403 INFO    : Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done
2018-01-31 14:25:47,404 INFO    : 
2018-01-31 14:25:47,451 INFO    : Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
2018-01-31 14:25:47,476 INFO    : Calling hook: install_kernel
2018-01-31 14:25:48,720 INFO    : E: Can not write log (Is /dev/pts mounted?) - posix_openpt (2: No such file or directory)
2018-01-31 14:25:49,088 INFO    : Done.
2018-01-31 14:25:52,449 INFO    : Running depmod.
2018-01-31 14:25:52,573 INFO    : update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
2018-01-31 14:25:52,584 INFO    : Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
2018-01-31 14:25:52,585 INFO    : run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-112-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
2018-01-31 14:25:52,635 INFO    : run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-112-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
2018-01-31 14:25:52,638 INFO    : update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-112-generic
2018-01-31 14:25:56,070 INFO    : run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-112-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
2018-01-31 14:25:56,193 INFO    : Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
2018-01-31 14:25:56,274 INFO    : Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
2018-01-31 14:25:56,278 INFO    : Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
2018-01-31 14:25:56,385 INFO    : Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
2018-01-31 14:25:56,534 INFO    : Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
2018-01-31 14:25:56,633 INFO    : Replacing config file /run/grub/menu.lst with new version
2018-01-31 14:25:56,657 INFO    : Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done
2018-01-31 14:25:56,657 INFO    : 
2018-01-31 14:25:56,966 INFO    : W: --force-yes is deprecated, use one of the options starting with --allow instead.
2018-01-31 14:25:56,992 INFO    : Calling hook: post_install
2018-01-31 14:25:56,992 INFO    : Calling hook: unmount_partitions
2018-01-31 14:25:56,993 INFO    : Unmounting target filesystem
2018-01-31 14:26:00,672 INFO    : Calling hook: convert
2018-01-31 14:26:00,673 INFO    : Converting /tmp/tmpJlEQzc to qcow2, format /var/local/machines//tmpJlEQzc.qcow2
2018-01-31 14:26:01,987 INFO    : Calling hook: fix_ownership
2018-01-31 14:26:02,276 INFO    : Calling hook: deploy
```

With virsh I can start the guest, but it seems not to boot. I can't establish a Console oder SSH Connection.

Is vmbuilder (aka ubuntu-vm-builder) deprecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **virt-install**:

```
virt-install -n pcname --memory 8000 --vcpus 8 --os-variant ubuntu16.04 --disk path=/var/local/machines/pcname.img,bus=sata,size=88 --network bridge=br0 --location /var/local/iso/ubuntu-16.04.3-server-amd64.iso --hvm
```

Now it's working like I wanted it to.